# how to merge 2 tables with one request

Tags: mysql, sql

so i got 2 tables with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE courses(
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  title varchar(255) default '',
  primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE course_dates(
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  course_id bigint,
  `date` date,
  key idx(course_id,date),
  primary key(id)
);
```

so courses are stored in first table and course dates in second (each course can have unlimited number of dates)

i need to get all course rows (with all its dates) at one time using one query

for example, if i have tables with such data:

```
courses:
id | title
1  | course#1
2  | course#2

course_dates:
id | course_id | date
1  | 1         | 2012-12-25
2  | 1         | 2012-12-27
3  | 1         | 2012-12-31
4  | 2         | 2012-12-23
5  | 2         | 2012-12-30
```

then i need result rows like this:

```
id | course_id | date       | title
1  | 1         | 2012-12-25 | course#1
2  | 1         | 2012-12-27 | course#1
3  | 1         | 2012-12-31 | course#1
4  | 2         | 2012-12-23 | course#2
5  | 2         | 2012-12-30 | course#2
```

Comment: `+1` for giving sample records with desired result. `:D`

Comment: this was the only way to get the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` will do.

```
SELECT  b.*, a.title
FROM    Courses a
        INNER JOIN Courses_Dates b
            ON a.id = b.Course_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b06c/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with `ORDER BY` clause*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b06c/5)

To learn more about joins, see the link below

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Probably with an ORDER BY clause so that course IDs are grouped together and course dates are shown in date order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yep much better, I added a link with `Order By` clause on it `:D`